# What is the difference between an array of characters and a single linear array?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, types, nomenclature

I'm new to java and I need help learning nomenclature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of characters is just a linear array of `char` values. An array can be anything, primitive or object; `Object[]`, `char[]`, `Comparable[]` and an array of a class named `Car` (`Car[]`) are all valid arrays.